# Convert Time stored as integer to datetime

Tags: vb.net, time, string-formatting

I have time stored as integer in a database

Example: `11325` means `01:13:25`

i am trying to make a function to do this work

i used the following code:

```
 Public Function GetTimeFromInt(ByVal intTime As Integer) As DateTime


    Dim strTemp As String = intTime.ToString("D6")

    strTemp = strTemp.Insert(4, ":").Insert(2, ":")

    Dim dtResult As DateTime = Date.ParseExact(strTemp, "HH:mm:ss", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)

    Return dtResult


End Function
```

And it is working fine. But i want to now if there is a way to do this using string formatting maybe like `int.ToString("nn:nn:nn")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
123456.ToString("00:00:00")
```

This will give `12:34:56`.